# What is a computer year?

Tags: algorithms, terminology, runtime-analysis

In one of the text book its mentioned that 'running time of this algorithm is 200 computer years'. Can somebody please explain what is the meaning of a computer year?

Comment: Which textbook? Most likely a computer year means a year of running the computer working on the problem.

Comment: 2oo times the distance a usual computer travels during a single year ;). Probably some number of instructions, based on some average instructions per second.

Comment: It's like [dog years](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unusual_units_of_measurement#Dog_year), i.e. a measure of time used to approximate the equivalent age of a computer in terms of an average human's life span. Since most computers/humans are put out of work after 3/65 years, a computer year is roughly 17 days. Or am I doing this wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Computer years, like man hours, are a measure of work. A computer year is the work one computer (of some agreed-upon speed...) performs in a year. 365 computers working in parallel for a day also perform one computer year of work.